# Keyboard key events repeating all the time (endlessly)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, autohotkey

My notebook keyboard is repeating key events in Windows, every 2 seconds I get these 2 events:

KeyDown (LButton OemClear 255)

KeyUp (LButton OemClear 255)

The pair of events keep firing and repeating endlessly.

I've already replaced the notebook keyboard twice, but it didn't solve the problem :(

Any idea of what kind of problem is this?

Should I format my computer to see if it's software related? I use Windows 7 Home Premium 32b.

Or it's guaranteed to be a hardware problem? What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

LButton is the left mouse button in Autohotkey code; therefore a first step could be to use a different mouse and see whether this solves the problem. It could also be that somehow buttons from a joystick or keypad presses are registered as LButton somehow. Incidentally, what happens when these events get registered? What do you see? I am assuming this is obstructing your use of the computer in some way; but how?

Comment: it’s a notebook. Of course it’s obstructive, if the system thinks that the LMB is constantly being clicked.
@LD2008, do you have an external mouse? If not, try plugging one in.

Comment: @Synetechinc.: It could be that the OP is using some AHK script that sends mouse clicks to an invisible or non-existing control (these would be visible in a log). There are various ways in which it might not be obstructive (I could easily write a script that does that); I was trying to establish whether he experienced mouse clicks, or some other weird behaviour. Moreover, since I do not know how he is registering these key presses, nor why he even added the AHK tag, the OS might be registering something that isn't a mouse click at all. In short, we need more info.

Comment: @Synetechinc.: And I have already suggested that he try a (different) mouse.

Comment: I didn’t suggest a *different* mouse, I suggested an external mouse at all—as opposed to the built-in trackpad. ;)

Comment: @Synetechinc.: OK, I assumed that he'd try any mouse at all then, in case he hadn't been using a mouse.